# jquery function is not called on single click rather gets called on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my application. Here is my code:

```
$("#imgphonemain").toggle(addphonerows, "remove function");
$("#imgsms").toggle(addsmsrows, "remove function");        

function addphonerows(event) {
    removesmsrowsbyphone("imgsms");
    addrowsbyphone("imgphone");
}

function addsmsrows(event) {
    removephonerowsbysms("imgsms");
    addrowsbysms("imgphone");
}
```

This basically adds a row into HTML, if I click the `imgsms` button it removes the phone row and inserts the SMS row, and if click on the `imgphonemain` button it removes the SMS row and inserts the phone row. This function does not work on a single click. It should called on double click. Can you help?

Comment: In my ignorance I see no click handler in your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give 2 function as a parameter to toggle handler.

check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/6swgP/

```
$("#imgphonemain").toggle(add, remove);

function add(){
alert("add")
}


function remove(){
alert("remove")
}
```

Comment: i am actually giving two paramaters. $("#imgphonemain").toggle(addphonerows, removephonerows); in the question remove function means a functoin.